# Pergunta de baixa qualidade, porém, aceitável e respondida pelo próprio autor

Tags: suporte

O título já diz tudo.

Esse é o tópico:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58260/como-criar-um-arquivo-com-file-put-contents-no-servidor-localhost

Fiquei confuso se deveria marcar para fechar a resposta do próprio autor da pergunta, mas a pergunta responde, de forma vaga, a questão dele mesmo.

A pegunta que tenho é, é realmente válido manter esse tipo de dado no SO?

Particularmente julgo isso como algo inútil e de baixíssima qualidade.
Entretanto, fico indeciso se deve ser excluída ou não.

Comment: Ainda estou pouco aqui no SOpt, mas como as regras parecem ser as mesmas do SO, acredito que o que deve ser feito é um *`down vote`* (esta resposta não é útil), além de sinalizar como `esta não é uma resposta`. No teu exemplo a resposta não é uma resposta, assim como a pergunta é bem má formulada. É um bom posicionamento o seu, já que há muita coisa deste nível aqui no SOpt, pelo que tenho notado.

Comment: Eu acho que com a resposta que ele deu vale a pena manter a pergunta fechada. Acho que não ajudará ninguém no futuro.

Comment: Converti a resposta em comentário. A pergunta de fato precisaria de mais informações para poder ser reaberta. @BrunoCésar, no geral concordo com o que você disse, as regras básicas aqui são as mesmas do SO. Porém, algumas coisas aqui são diferentes, e temos margem para sermos ainda mais diferentes se quisermos. Ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com